# Jquery that doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

See: http://qwer.se/stack/trailer/

It works fine in FF, C & SF but not in IE. Cant find the error.

IE says: "'undefined' is null or not an object"

**This is the script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

// open popup when image is clicked
$('img').click(function(){
var $movieObj = $(".tdt object"); // Cache jQuery object
var imgID = $(this).attr("alt"),
    movieVal = $("param[name=movie]", $movieObj).val(),
    embedSrc = $("embed", $movieObj).attr("src");
$movieObj
    .find("param[name=movie]").val(movieVal.replace(/MY-ID-NUMBER/, imgID)).end()
    .find("embed", $movieObj).attr("src", embedSrc.replace(/MY-ID-NUMBER/, imgID)).end();
$(".tdb").show();
});


// close popup + restor value to default
$('.tdb').click(function(){
var default1 = "http://www.player.filmtrailer.com/v3.4/player.swf?file=http://se.player-feed.previewnetworks.com/cinema/MY-ID-NUMBER/4601100213-1/";
var default2 = "http://www.player.filmtrailer.com/v3.4/player.swf?file=http://se.player-feed.previewnetworks.com/cinema/MY-ID-NUMBER/4601100213-1/&display_title=over&menu=true&enable_link=true&default_quality=xxlarge&controlbar=over&autostart=true&backcolor=000000&frontcolor=ffffff&share=0&repeat=always&displayclick=play&volume=80&linktarget=_blank";
var $movieObj = $(".tdt object"); // Cache jQuery object
var imgID = $(this).attr("alt"),
movieVal = $("param[name=movie]", $movieObj).val(),
embedSrc = $("embed", $movieObj).attr("src");
$(".tdt object").find("param[name=movie]").val(default1);
$(".tdt object").find("embed", $movieObj).attr("src", default2);
$(".tdb").hide();
});

});
</script>
```

I have added ID to "param" and "embed" and also changed the script into this now. But it still doesn't work in IE.

```
// open popup when image is clicked
$('img').click(function(){
var $movieObj = $(".tdt object"); // Cache jQuery object
var imgID = $(this).attr("alt"),
    movieVal = $('#testing').val(),
    embedSrc = $('#player').attr("src");
$movieObj
    .find('#testing').val(movieVal.replace(/MY-ID-NUMBER/, imgID)).end()
    .find('#player').attr("src", embedSrc.replace(/MY-ID-NUMBER/, imgID)).end();
$(".tdb").show();
});


// close popup when background is clicked + restor value to default
$('.tdb').click(function(){
var default1 = "http://www.player.filmtrailer.com/v3.4/player.swf?file=http://se.player-feed.previewnetworks.com/cinema/MY-ID-NUMBER/4601100213-1/";
var default2 = "http://www.player.filmtrailer.com/v3.4/player.swf?file=http://se.player-feed.previewnetworks.com/cinema/MY-ID-NUMBER/4601100213-1/&display_title=over&menu=true&enable_link=true&default_quality=xxlarge&controlbar=over&autostart=true&backcolor=000000&frontcolor=ffffff&share=0&repeat=always&displayclick=play&volume=80&linktarget=_blank";
var $movieObj = $(".tdt object"); // Cache jQuery object
var imgID = $(this).attr("alt"),
    movieVal = $('#testing').val(),
    embedSrc = $('#player').attr("src");
$movieObj
    .find('#testing').val(default1).end()
    .find('#player').attr("src", default2).end();
$(".tdb").hide();
});
```

**This is how I sloved it (might not be prity, but it works):**

```
$('img').click(function(){
var default1 = '<object class="tot" width="960" height="540"><param id="testa" name="movie" value="http://www.player.filmtrailer.com/v3.4/player.swf?file=http://se.player-feed.previewnetworks.com/cinema/';
var default2 = $(this).attr("alt");
var default3 = '/4601100213-1/><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><embed id="player" name="player" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.player.filmtrailer.com/v3.4/player.swf?file=http://se.player-feed.previewnetworks.com/cinema/';
var default4 = '/4601100213-1/&display_title=over&menu=true&enable_link=true&default_quality=xxlarge&controlbar=over&autostart=true&backcolor=000000&frontcolor=ffffff&share=0&repeat=always&displayclick=play&volume=80&linktarget=_blank" width="960" height="540"allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed></object>';
$('.tdt').html(default1 + default2 + default3 + default2 + default4);
$(".tdb").show();
});



$('.tdb').click(function(){
$('.tdt').html('');
$(".tdb").hide();
});
```

Comment: in which line IE says is there error?

Comment: Sorry amosrivera, didn't se your comment. I have solved the code in a nother way now. Will update the question soon. If you want you can comment on the new solution (it might not prity, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

Using the IE debugger shows that this bit is throwing the error:

```
$movieObj
    .find("param[name=movie]").val(movieVal.replace(/MY-ID-NUMBER/, imgID)).end()
    .find("embed", $movieObj).attr("src", embedSrc.replace(/MY-ID-NUMBER/, imgID)).end();
```

.

Looking at the source in the IE dev tools shows that there aren't any `param` tags inside the `object` tag and that the embed tag is goofed up (`</embed/>`). I'm not sure what's causing this though.

[shotInTheDark]`<embed>` is a self-closing tag and perhaps IE is garbling your non-self-closing tag.[/shotInTheDark]

Comment: Hi Rfvgyhn. Thanks for answer. I'm not very good at Jquery. Can you provide a code wich I can test?